# Spy on a Java Class method calls

Tags: java

Is it possible to spy on the method calls being made to instances of a Java class. I know I could achieve this using `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler`. I'm wondering if there are other easier ways which don't involve modifying the source code of the classes?

EDIT:
For example `java.util.HashMap`. The source code for this class is not available - at least for me it's not when running under Oracle's JDK. How would I intercept the calls made to the put(...) method. I would like to inspect the parameters in the call.

Comment: How do you want to "spy"? You want to see variables values etc?

Comment: Do you want to be notified when a method is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do this with [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
You're just have to declare pointcuts of your code, which you're want to 'spy'. In a few words - you're might declare annotations, put them above methods signatures, and all annotated methods might been modified by compiler in a compile time (or been modified in time of loading bytecode to jvm) without needs to modify their source code.

[AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) is useful for this.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. How do I declare pointcuts in java.util.HashMap?

Comment: For any method of HashMap: execution(* java.util.HashMap.*(..))

Comment: I'm using Spring AOP, here you may get lots of information about it (and about AOP in general) http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html

Comment: Great thanks. Looks like this is definitely what I'm after - afraid I can't upvote your answer yet - my reputation's too low :-(

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your problem:
You want to execute your own code every time a non-static method call to a specific class is executed. I also assume you have full access to the JVM environment.

Take a look at [JMX Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html). These beans are interfaces to the behaviour of the Java Virtual Machine.

Also look at the [Java Agent](http://javahowto.blogspot.be/2006/07/javaagent-option.html) specification for modifying existing applications where you do not have access to the MAIN method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JMSPY](https://github.com/dmgcodevil/jmspy). Jmspy is a java library that allows recording of java methods invocations, saving data into a file called snapshot and analyzing it using jmspy viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). It allows you to insert hooks into calls to methods and execute arbitrary code before and after the body of the method runs. It solves this using a custom class-loader.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest studying [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) which allows separation of cross-cutting concerns (logging etc.) .

This way, specifying pointcuts for your methods you may "spy" on the methods.